# Why are my Player Input Unity Events started twice?

Tags: unity

I'm using the (new) "Input System" package and the "Player Input" component on my player prefab like this:

[image: Player Input]

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public void Fire(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (!context.started) return;
        Debug.Log($"Fire!");
    }
}
```

The odd thing is, this method is invoked twice with `context.started == true`. What am I missing here? Why is the method invoked twice?

A minimal working example to reproduce the behaviour can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/timbuethe/Input-System-Test).

**EDIT**

The player joins automatically through the "Player Input Manager":

[image: Player Input Manager]

Comment: Any chance you have more than one player in the scene?

Comment: No, it's just one player. The player is spawned automatically when I press any button. I use "Player Input Manager" to achieve this. Let me add another screenshot to the question. You can also checkout and start the example project I added to GitHub, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this issue by creating a brand-new project with the Input System and using your sample code. Nothing changed, but I can definitely suggest a workaround for this.

While using the *Player Input Manager* led me to the same results as yours, just spawning the *Player* prefab via custom code (or adding it to the scene beforehand) worked just fine. The `Fire()` callback was being called once only when the mouse button was pressed, as expected. Pew pew!

According to the [scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Plugins.PlayerInput.PlayerInputManager.html), the *Player Input Manager* «manages joining and leaving of players», and that's it. I think you can smoothly get rid of this component and write your own Player Manager, which deals with spawning your player prefab and toggling user input during cutscenes and stuff.

---

The behaviour you are experiencing is likely to be a bug. The new Input System is a handy alternative to the limited, built-in input manager, but it's [still under development](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem). You may [report it](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Contributing.html) to the Unity team as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot liggiorgio! I will go ahead and report this. Let's see if they have an answer. Or even fix it, if it turns out to be indeed a bug in Input System.